# 3 mysql table join but not getting expected result that i want

Tags: mysql

Here my table:
**account**

```
ac             name
120            Tom
130            Jony
140            Jone
```

**bread_sale**

```
ac             pcs        amount       date
120            12           60         2018-01-03
120            10           50         2018-01-04
140            8            40         2018-01-04
130            5            25         2018-01-05
```

**water_sale**

```
ac             pcs        amount       date
130            2            30         2018-01-03
130            5            75         2018-01-04
140            3            45         2018-01-04
130            4            60         2018-01-05
120            5            75         2018-01-07
```

Here's the query that I have tried:

```
select account.ac, 
       account.name, 
       bread_sale.amount as BSAmount,  
       bread_sale.date as BSDate, 
       water_sale.amount as WSAmount, 
       water_sale.date as WSDate
from account left outer join bread_sale on account.ac = bread_sale.ac 
             left outer join water_sale on water_sale.ac = account.ac 
order by account.ac
```

This is the result:

```
ac             name       BSAmount   BSdate       WSAmount   WSdate
120            Tom        30         2018-01-03   75         2018-01-07
120            Tom        75         2018-01-04   75         2018-01-07
130            Jony       45         2018-01-05   30         2018-01-03
130            Jony       60         2018-01-05   75         2018-01-04
130            Jony       75         2018-01-05   60         2018-01-05
140            Jone       75         2018-01-04   45         2018-01-04
```

But I want to obtain something like this:

```
ac             name       BSAmount   BSdate       WSAmount   WSdate
120            Tom        60         2018-01-03   75         2018-01-07
120            Tom        50         2018-01-04   0          2018-01-07
130            Jony       25         2018-01-05   30         2018-01-03
130            Jony       0          2018-01-05   75         2018-01-04
130            Jony       0          2018-01-05   60         2018-01-05
140            Jone       40         2018-01-04   45         2018-01-04
```

In 2018-01-07 Tom did not sale water but I get 75 amount. 
Someone help me, please

Comment: Is there some sort of expectation that there is a water sale for every bread sale (and vice versa) otherwise your desired output doesn't make sense. - why do you have 120            Tom        60         2018-01-03   75         2018-01-07 on the same row for example?

Comment: Your last sentence may be wrong. Take a look to the last record in water_sale.

Comment: Your Second row Tom WS Amount is 0. How is that possible to get 0 on that row.

Comment: i don't understand how the expected result decide when to put 0 in BSAMount and WSAmount (you have 0 BSAmount in row 4 and 5, while for WSAmount you put it in row 2).

there's no correlation between water and bread sale, it will have more sense for me if you want the total sales for bread and water for each account for each date (so each row have same date for both water and bread sale)

Comment: why don't you use single table for both water_sale and bread_sale by assigning sale type like 'ws' for water_sale and 'bs' for bread_sale  field in table.as all fields are same in both tables.

Comment: There's no fundamental relationship between bread and water. There's no reason for these to be separate tables. One way of overcoming that flaw is to redesign your schema. Another, less satisfactory, method is UNION

Comment: @Strawberry you're right but with the schema he has UNION is the only way to get anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achievable but messy and probably not very efficient. There is a relationship between the bread water and account on ac. It is possible to establish the maximum number of row numbers spanning bread and water and then rejoining on row number. Put another way bread and water are joined on a position basis (ie the order rows appear in the tables) The resulting query is horrible and parses the data more frequently than I would be comfortable with personally.

so

```
select * from
(
select c.ac cac,t.name tname,d.amount bsamount,  d.dt ddt,
         e.amount wsamount ,e.dt edt
         ,
         case when d.dt is not null and d.dt < e.dt then d.dt
               when d.dt is not null and e.dt is null then d.dt
         else e.dt
         end as sortorder
 from
(
select *
from
(
select bs.ac,
         if(bs.ac <> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:=bs.ac p
from bs
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by bs.ac,bs.dt
) a  
union 
(
select ac2,rn1,p1
from
(
select ws.ac ac2,
         if(ws.ac <> @p1,@rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn1,
         @p1:=ws.ac p1
from ws
cross join (select @rn1:=0,@p1:=0) r
order by ws.ac,ws.dt
) b
) 
) c
left join 
(
select bs.ac,pcs,amount,dt,
         if(bs.ac <> @p3,@rn3:=1,@rn3:=@rn3+1) rn3,
         @p3:=bs.ac p
from bs
cross join (select @rn3:=0,@p3:=0) r
order by bs.ac,bs.dt
) d
on d.ac = c.ac and  d.rn3 = c.rn
left join
(
select ws.ac,pcs,amount,dt,
         if(ws.ac <> @p4,@rn4:=1,@rn4:=@rn4+1) rn4,
         @p4:=ws.ac p
from ws
cross join (select @rn4:=0,@p4:=0) r
order by ws.ac,ws.dt
) e
on e.ac = c.ac and  e.rn4 = c.rn
join t on t.ac = c.ac
) f
order by cac , sortorder;

+------+-------+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| cac  | tname | bsamount | ddt        | wsamount | edt        | sortorder  |
+------+-------+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
|  120 | Tom   |       60 | 2018-01-03 |       75 | 2018-01-07 | 2018-01-03 |
|  120 | Tom   |       50 | 2018-01-04 |     NULL | NULL       | 2018-01-04 |
|  130 | Jony  |       25 | 2018-01-05 |       30 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-03 |
|  130 | Jony  |     NULL | NULL       |       75 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-04 |
|  130 | Jony  |     NULL | NULL       |       60 | 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-05 |
|  140 | Jone  |       40 | 2018-01-04 |       45 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-04 |
+------+-------+----------+------------+----------+------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i copy paste this code(query) into my database and try to pull result it's says some table does not exists.

Comment: I was too lazy to type your full table names you will need to substitute your table names

Answer (score 0):

```
select account.ac, 
   account.name, 
   bread_sale.amount as BSAmount,  
   bread_sale.date as BSDate, 
   water_sale.amount as WSAmount, 
   water_sale.date as WSDate
from account left outer join bread_sale on account.ac = bread_sale.ac 
             left outer join water_sale on water_sale.ac = bread_sale.ac 
order by account.ac
```

This Query would produce this result. Your zeros will be replaced by correct value. I hope may be you would need this reuslt.

```
ac             name       BSAmount   BSdate       WSAmount   WSdate
120            Tom        60         2018-01-03   75         2018-01-07
120            Tom        50         2018-01-04   75         2018-01-07
130            Jony       25         2018-01-05   30         2018-01-03
130            Jony       25         2018-01-05   75         2018-01-04
130            Jony       25         2018-01-05   60         2018-01-05
140            Jone       40         2018-01-04   45         2018-01-04
```